# React not triggering re-rendering of form inputs after state is updated via onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, use-state

I am trying to build out a verification code page.

If I create an individual state for each input box, and then use the code below, it works appropriately.

```
<input type="number" value={inputOne} className={styles.codeInput} onChange={e => setInputOne(e.target.value}/>
```

However, I was trying to consolidate the state for all four of the input boxes, into one state object.

Now, when I type in a number, it moves on to the next input, but it never renders the value. In dev tools, I see the value flash like it updates, but it still stays as "value" and not "value="1"" for example.

However, if I do anything else to my code, like for example, change a p tag's text, then suddenly it updates and the inputs show the correct value.

I'm just trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Here's my current code.

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import styles from '../../styles/SASS/login.module.scss'

export default function Verify(params) {
  const [verifCode, setVerifCode] = useState(['','','','']);

  const inputHandler = (e, index) => {
    // get event target value
    let value = e.target.value;
    // update state
    let newState = verifCode;
    newState[index] = value;
    setVerifCode(newState);
    // move focus to next input
    if (e.target.nextSibling) {
      e.target.nextSibling.focus()
    } else {
      // if at the last input, remove focus
      e.target.blur();
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.verify}>
      <p className={styles.title}>Verification</p>
      <p className={styles.message}>Please enter the verification code we sent to your email / mobile phone.</p>

      <div className={styles.form}>
        <input type="number" value={verifCode[0]} className={styles.codeInput} onChange={e => inputHandler(e, 0)}/>
        <input type="number" value={verifCode[1]} className={styles.codeInput} onChange={e => inputHandler(e, 1)}/>
        <input type="number" value={verifCode[2]} className={styles.codeInput} onChange={e => inputHandler(e, 2)}/>
        <input type="number" value={verifCode[3]} className={styles.codeInput} onChange={e => inputHandler(e, 3)}/>
      </div>

      <div className={styles.footer}>
        <button>Verify Code</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};
```

Comment: React does shallow compares to determine if state has changed, your `setVerifCode` is always pointing to the same reference, so they are equal.

Comment: ahhh. Gotcha. Any idea why it then appears to have worked if I edit anything else on the page ? Trying to understand what's happening in theory.

Comment: If some other state which is *not* shallow equal is changed in the component, it will trigger an update, which will render using the state you mutated in `verifCode`, even though react still doesn't know that `verifCode` has changed. The point is that react needs to be able to know when an update is needed, which is why you must *always* update state immutably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem lies in the following code

```
// update state
let newState = verifCode;
newState[index] = value;
setVerifCode(newState);
```

First line of the code just adds a pointer to the value `verifCode`.
You modify an element in that array, but `newState` is still the same variable `verifCode`. Even though the array elements have changed essentially it is still same variable (same reference).

Try something like:

```
// update state
const newState = [...verifCode]; // create a copy of the old verifCode, creating new array 
newState[index] = value; // modify element
setVerifCode(newState); // set the new array to the state
```

Comment: This answer is correct, though I'm not sure it emphasizes the point of "never attempt to mutate react state" quite heavily enough. State being treated as immutable is core to react's functioning, because without it, react cannot correctly determine when and when not trigger component updates. See https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data (and the bit just above that section) for an illuminating example from the docs.

Comment: See also https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html for help updating more complex state objects

Comment: You're absolutely right. That worked. Thanks. I'm still trying to wrap my head around to the second part of the question though. If it doesn't update the state on input, why when I then modify anything else on the page, and it re-renders, does the previously entered code appear in the inputs?

Comment: `[...verifCode]` creates a copy of the state and we never modify the original state, and this is what immutability is about. Unless I am missing something @thisisrandy

Comment: @YungNoey as Keith mentioned in his comment the value is set to react internal state but since the reference is not updated it wont re-render.  You triggering re-render via something else probably flushes the new state to the view.

Comment: @ssBarBee, I just wanted to make sure that OP understands clearly that there is this concept of immutability which is essential to react's functioning. You don't actually say "immutable" anywhere in your answer, so I was attempting to add that vocabulary to the discussion

Comment: agreed @thisisrandy :D I wanted to use more layman terms and avoid bringing immutability to the table :)